# Load image in collectionView inside tableview using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I want to show image using sdWebImage to an image inside collectionView Cell which is inside tableView cell.
`How to do it ? and where i should write the sdWebImage api ?` **in CategogyRow.swift** ?
I have 3 different cell where i will be doing the same thing.

> [Link i reffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154980/ios-load-images-from-url-using-sdwebimage)

Code :

**ViewController.swift :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

**CategoryRow.swift**

```
    class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    }

    extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 12
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
            cell.imageView.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "url"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))`
            return cell
        }

    }

    extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
            let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
            let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
            let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        }

    }
```

**VideoCell.swift**

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Looks good. But whats the error?

Comment: i have 3 different cell whose implementation is same. so is this a correct way or shall i download json first in viewcontroller and then pass the required jaon data to each cell ?@ThatlazyiOSGuy웃

Comment: SDWebimage handles all the caching ...So, its ok to load images as you have done

Comment: okay thank you :) . I'll keep the question if someone else is looking for same implementation.

Comment: I do exactly the same thing but I upload the images erroneously, you can see my publication I hope you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571371/how-to-load-image-with-sdwebimage-correctly-in-uicollectionview-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment99737004_56571371