# How to load image with SDWebImage correctly in UICollectionView in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage, uicollectionreusableview

I'm facing the following problem, well I have a custom collection view, where I upload an image from the URL I get from a service, everything works fine at the moment but sometimes when scrolling or when I leave the screen and return, my collection view customized it is altered, it does not load correctly, I have seen several posts where they present the same problem in different cases, but trying to conclude that my problem is at the moment of using the **SDWebImage** library. I have seen that they use methods like the prepareForReuse setting the image to nil but still my problem persists.

So you see the first time

[image]

and then it looks like this the second time

[image]

Here this my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemMenuFilterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemMenuFilterCollectionViewCell
         cell.mImgProduct.image = nil
         cell.mImgProduct.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].photo!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

        cell.mTxtProductName.text = mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].shortName
        cell.mTxtBrand.text = mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].marca
        cell.mTxtStore.text = mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].tienda
        cell.mTxtPrice.text = mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].price
        cell.mRatingStar.rating = mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].valor?.toDouble() ?? 0

        return cell

    }
```

As I mentioned, I think that my problem is in charge of the image with the libreta since I comment on that line of code `cell.mImgProduct.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: mDataListProducts[indexPath.row].photo!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))`
All function ok, I would like to know a better way to do it or maybe correct something that is happening to me.

I also have this in the prepareforReuse of my customviewcell but still nothing.

```
class ItemMenuFilterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mRatingStar: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mImgProduct: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mTxtProductName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mTxtBrand: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mTxtStore: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mTxtPrice: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.mImgProduct.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
        self.mImgProduct.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading images in viewWillAppear function ?

Comment: Have you tried the code from this comment: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/1024#issuecomment-384727983 ?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik 
executed a service in the viewDidLoad of the contractor and if the service runs correctly I do an mCollectionView.reload ()

Comment: @dbenitobaldeon Explain with English ?

Comment: Excuse me, @OmerTekbiyik , 
I just edited my question

Comment: @Cristik If I tried all that but still nothing.

Comment: Looking again at the screenshot, it kooks more like a layout issue rather than `sd_setImage` one. Do you have the proper constraints for the contents of the cell?

Comment: I also thought about it but as I mentioned when I commented on the code line that loads the image to my UIImage, the screen is loaded correctly 
even so that would not explain because when scrolling down and then returning everything is already loaded correctly. It can be a tail problem @Cristik

Comment: Maybe it’s related to image view’s content mode?

Comment: I've seen in other post that they load it in another way using methods with escaping and all that, I think it's a good practice but I see that the majority recommends to avoid so much code using SDWebImage. @Cristik

Comment: Even if your problem is directly caused by `sd_setImage`, I don't think the library is the problematic one. I have a feeling that your problem is caused by the way the image view is configured, and it's only exposed by the fact that `sd_setImage` is asynchronous.

Comment: OMG !! I removed all the constraint and it works ok! I'm not sure it's the best way. 
but if I leave my view without constraint when I run my app on other devices I will have problems @Cristik

Comment: So my assumption was right :) You need constraints to properly layout the cells, however you need the proper constraints.

Comment: As mention by @Cristik, it is definitely the issue of constraints. You should give a `proportional height constraint` to the image and the `scale mode should be aspect fit`.